# Gunicorn not starting anymore after adding PostgreSQL in Docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, gunicorn

I have a Django project that I'm trying to dockerize. I successfully added Django with gunicorn and nginx to Docker. However, when trying to add PostgreSQL, I encountered an issue. My Postgres container starts, but my gunicorn one doesn't start anymore, and I get this error in the logs, so it indeed seems like it comes from Postgres :

```
C:\Users\stephane.bernardelli>docker logs testapp-django_gunicorn-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 244, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 225, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 203, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 98, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 91, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 36, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1461, in check
    *cls._check_indexes(databases),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1864, in _check_indexes
    connection.features.supports_covering_indexes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/features.py", line 84, in is_postgresql_11
    return self.connection.pg_version >= 110000
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 354, in pg_version
    with self.temporary_connection():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 639, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 284, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 243, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 244, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 225, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 203, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I tried changing the host IP address of postgres in my settings, but it only changed the error, but didn't solve it.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  rabbitmq3:
    image: rabbitmq:3-alpine
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
    networks:
      - main

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    hostname: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=Scripts Application
    networks:
      - main
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - postgresql-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  django_gunicorn:
    volumes:
      - static:/static
      - media:/media
    env_file:
      - env
    build:
      context: .
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    command: sh -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && gunicorn main.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - main

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/static
      - media:/media
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - django_gunicorn
    networks:
      - main

  celery:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    command: celery -A main worker -P eventlet -c 100 -l INFO
    env_file:
      - env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq3
      - django_gunicorn
      - postgres
    networks:
      - main

networks:
  main:

volumes:
  postgresql-data:
  static:
  media:
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.10.5-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBEFFERED = 1 

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN \
 apk add --no-cache postgresql-libs && \
 apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc musl-dev postgresql-dev && \
 python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir && \
 apk --purge del .build-deps
COPY ./src /app

WORKDIR /app
```

I have absolutely no idea where the problem could be coming from, so I'd be glad if someone could guide me on how to solve it, thank you in advance !

Comment: Have you changed you db config in django settings? It's no longer 127.0.0.1, it's name of your db container so postgres

Comment: That was that...such a dumb problem, I don't even know how I didn't think of it...Thank you !